# How to check a Python Set for a string

Tags: python, string, list, duplicates, set

Hopefully this doesn't get downvoted on the title but couldn't think of a better way of explaining the issue.

Based on suggestions I've seen on Stack, I am using Sets to ignore duplicate lines which  works a treat until I get a use case where the line changes slightly but I still want to filter that line out as a duplicate. In my example, I cannot seem to be able to search a string for a certain keyword so in my example below, I  exclude any new line where the firs column, which is the ID, already exists, in this case London.

For example.

```
London,Sold,2021-12-07,1000000,301909
London,Sold,2021-12-07,1000000,999999
```

So I wanted to know if it was possible to just check whether the ID London exists in my Set before adding the line or ignoring but I can't find any way to do this. I tried tuples but not sure that is my solution and I cannot create a set from list.  My simple test case is as follows and the end result is I only get the line in my set, not the testline as is happening now.

```
testline = 'London,Sold,2021-12-07,1000000,301909'
id = 'London'

j="testline2"
seen = set()
seen.add(testline)

if id not in seen:
    seen.add(j)

print seen
```

Comment: If you find such a near-duplicate, would you want to keep the first or the second encountered item?

Comment: keep the first occurrence

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you want a dict, where the key is the first value, rather than a set.

```
seen = {}
id = testline.partition(',')[0]
seen[id] = testline
...
if id not in seen:
    ...
```

Comment: Can you please change `id` name? Not good practice to shadow built-ins..

Comment: Sure, will do for future posts, was just using that as an example but will remember for best practices. thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
testline = 'London,Sold,2021-12-07,1000000,301909'
id = 'London'

j="testline2"
seen = set()
for element in testline.split(',')
    seen.add(element)
if id not in seen:
    seen.add(j)

print seen
```

Answer (score 0):

You're near to the solution:

```
testline = ['London','Sold','2021-12-07','1000000','301909'] #updated
id = 'London'

j="testline2"
seen = set(testline) #updated
if id not in seen:
    seen.add(j)

print (seen )
```

Comment: What's different than in OP's code? I don't think the indentation was the problem.

Comment: Ah, you split `testline` to a list. You should mention that in your answer. However, Unless you tell OP how to do this programmatically, I don't think this in itself will help much.

Comment: Thanks @tobias_k, I shall consider your suggestion in my future answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract the first split of your comma separated string and add it to your set. For this, you can either your `x.split(',', 1)[0]` or `x.partition(',')[0]`.

The logic is identical to the commonly used `itertools` recipe `unique_everseen`, [available in the official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes).

The recipe has been re-implemented in 3rd party [`toolz.unique`](http://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#toolz.itertoolz.unique), which can save you reinventing the wheel:

```
from toolz import unique

L = ['London,Sold,2021-12-07,1000000,301909',
     'London,Sold,2021-12-07,1000000,999999']

res = list(unique(L, key=lambda x: x.partition(',')[0]))

print(res)
['London,Sold,2021-12-07,1000000,301909']
```